# How to create a RadioButton style with template binding for enumeration and images?

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button

I'm trying to learn XAML Styles better.

In writing the XAML (WPF) for a project I'm working on, I have multiple uses of code like:

```
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CurrentPen.CustomStrokeType, Converter={StaticResource StrokeTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static e:PenEnum.LinePen}}"
                Width="25" Height="25" Foreground="Blue" GroupName="CustomStroke"
                         >
                <RadioButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Image x:Name="PART_Image" Source="/Doctor_Desk;component/Images/Line.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="/Doctor_Desk;component/Images/Line-On.png"  />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </RadioButton.Style>
            </RadioButton>


public class StrokeTypeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (PenEnum)parameter == (PenEnum)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? parameter : null;
        }
    }
```

The above code works well to display a button with RadioButton behavior. The default "Off" image (i.e., "Line.png") is replaced with "Line-On.png" when the RadioButton is clicked. However, I have many of these RadioButton's -- each with a different On and Off image as appropriate for their respective e:PenEnum enumeration. Unfortunately, this basic style is repeated multiple times.

The only difference between all these buttons is the e:PenEnum value and the On and Off images.

Can this style be placed in the resources and reused for each button, allowing for the specific differences of each button?

How can this be done and still allow for different enumeration, on, and off images for each RadioButton?

TIA

Comment: I believe the best solution is to create custom radio button (for example, `ImageRadioButton`) inherited from `RadioButton` with dependency properties like `OnImage`, `OffImage` and `Pen`.

Comment: @Maxim So don't use a resource Style?

Comment: Your style will be defined only once for the `ImageRadioButton`.

Comment: @Maxm Got it..Thank you.